# Loop interrupt stops all loops, not just the one designated

Tags: ev3, programming

I have been using loop interrupts for a while, and not had an issue... until now. And it is driving me nuts.

My program has 2 main loops, titled "touch" and "end" with two more nested in the "touch" loop, both titled "01"- these are just for turning with the gyro. I've attached pics so you can see this in detail.

The problem loop is the "touch" loop - the main nested one. I have a separate thread running to check the state of a switch. When it is pressed, I have a loop interrupt for the "touch" loop only. Since it is nested, and I only have one loop interrupt, I would expect it to pick up with the "end" loop and start over... but instead it ends the program, as if I interrupted both "touch" and "end".

I'm obviously missing something here... anyone with ideas, please speak up.

[image: Full program][image: Start][image: End]

Comment: Is the code after the "end" loop executed? The program could also terminate because of an error, is there an error icon or message on the EV3 display?

Comment: Also perhaps try renaming the outer loop. Perhaps "end" has a specific undocumented meaning...

Comment: I'm guessing that the interrupts in loop 03 are somehow being triggered.

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve The sound at the very end does play, and there are no error messages. Changing the names of the loops does nothing different.